# Linux HA - Best Heartbeat hardware solution

Tags: linux, cluster, heartbeat

Hi all I would ask anyone what is the best layer 2 medium for heartbeat in Linux and how it's best configured.

More precisely I've been thinking about a dedicated NIC for that purpose but then i thought that if a switch breaks then i would loose the heartbeat connection for most of the cluster and STONITH 'BUM'!!! Will probably loose my job after :)

Distributing the heartbeat onto the main NICs of every node trough a vif sounds reasonable but im not sure if this is the best option (at least the switches are redundant to some extent).

Is it possible to use heartbeat over a bonded interface and that sounds reasonable?
Do you have any other tip/solution for that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using keepalived over bonded interfaces. Each slave interface is connected to a different switch. When one interface/switch fails, the other interface/switch should be enough. When both interfaces fail, the VIP is shifted to the other node in the cluster. Keepalived is another HA solution similar to heartbeat.

Comment: Thanks, thinking about it sounds reasonable I've never tried keepalived but will give it a shot later.

Comment: I am not suggesting you to change to keepalived. I am just describing my case. You can choose any of them.